# How did Vulcans view half-human-half-Vulcan hybrids?

Tags: star-trek

We know of several half-human-half-Vulcan hybrids in Star Trek (Spock, Elizabeth).

How did Vulcans view them? Were they viewed with the same condescension as "emotional"/"illogical" humans? Half-and-half? Or as "real" Vulcans?

Comment: If the Abrams-verse is any indication, the Vulcan council members considered the half-human Spock, impressive, "despite his handicap of having a human mother." The other Vulcan children he grew up with were also quite dismissive of him because of his heritage and potential outbursts of emotion.

Comment: I wouldn't vote to close this because it's interesting, but isn't it too broad?  I suspect the answer varies from TOS to the other series' and to some or all of the books...  I know this was touched on it at least one book ("The Lost Years," set between TOS and TMP) and in that one many Vulcans looked down on Spock for his human side.

Comment: @Ward - how many half hybrids were there total? I only know of 2.

Comment: @DVK You said "several" in the question, I actually only know of Spock.  IF there are only 2, that would largely take care of the too broad aspect, although you still have to deal with TOS, movies, books, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ST V: The Final Frontier, we see Spock's inner turmoil manifested as seeing Sarek look upon his newly born half-human son and saying, almost disgustedly "so human".

Spock himself plays down his human side during the Original Series - indicating a self-repression caused by the Vulcan culture he grew up in.

I can't think of all that many other specific instances of Vulcan interaction with half-Vulcans - but even before Star Trek (the reboot movie), I'm pretty sure that there was the same disdain/subtext there.

Comment: `even before Star Trek`?  Do you have something to share - are you Vulcan?

Comment: hehe - forgot to state the reboot movie

Comment: "I can't think of all that many other specific instances of Vulcan interaction with half-Vulcans" - the TAS episode "Yesteryear" shows a young Spock being tormented by his peers (Vulcan children are just as horrible as human children when it comes to this sort of thing), and an adult Vulcan openly questioning his honesty when he's asking for help.

Comment: According to one of the novels (Pandora Principle?), Saavik also had a hard time on Vulcan due to her hybrid nature. Which is really weird, considering that a Vulcan/Romulan hybrid is basically just Vulcan.

Comment: @Omegacron - Romulans are emotional, and have been antagonistic towards Vulcans and (then) the Federation for many centuries - it would be simple for a Vulcan to construct logic that Romulans are inferior and therefore a Vulcan/Romulan hybrid is inferior.

Answer (score 0):

In TAS:Yesteryear, Vulcan children are mean to young Spock for being half human, teasing him, etc.  He gains partial respect after learning how to do the Vulcan Neck Pinch.

*Star Trek* (2009) has similar themes.